# append elements to vector in R returns only latest value

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, append

I would like to read through a for loop some data in a dataframe and create a ratio using them. The ratio is well calculated as the singular output is fine. However, I wish to create a vector out of the ratios. The issue is that the output of the vector is always the latest ratio. Could anybody help on that, please? Thanks.

```
for(i in seq(from = 0, to = nrow(newdata2018), by = 2)){
  ratio1vector <- NULL

  ratio1 <- newdata2018$A_01[i]/newdata2018$A[i]*100
  ratio1vector <- c(ratio1vector, ratio1)

  print(ratio1vector)
}
```

Comment: Your problem is `ratio1vector <- NULL` in each loop. Are you aware that you can do this without any loop?

Comment: Thank you @docendo discimus for your reply. Could you please explain your comment more in detail? I am not sure I understood.

Comment: Just remove this line from your loop: `ratio1vector <- NULL`. This deletes your existing values in every loop

Comment: ok, I see. But wouldn't I need to create an empty vector first anyway?

Comment: Yes you can but you have to do that *before* the loop.

Comment: I have created a vector external to the loop and now it works fine!

Comment: Thank you for the help @docendodiscimus :)

Comment: Or just do it the R-way (vectorized): `newdata2018$A_01[c(FALSE, TRUE)]/newdata2018$A[c(FALSE, TRUE)]*100`. This is all you need, actually.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue is sufficient to create the vector externally from the loop.